# soap request gui and its corrosponding code trying in cf

Tags: soap, coldfusion, lucee

I am trying to fix the SOAP request so i can see the results, but something is not right, my soap request is like this:

main wsdl,

```
https://hiddenurl.oraclecloud.com/foundationParties/PersonService?wsdl
```

and when using soapUI, i use this

[image]

now i can lots of methods

[image]

and under that i choose one of the items which is processPerson and create a request 1 and add my authentication and soap body and get results when i run it,

but in Coldfusion,

```
<cftry>
    <cfscript>
        httpService = new http();
        httpService.setUrl("https://hiddenurl.oraclecloud.com/foundationParties/PersonService?wsdl");
        httpService.setMethod("GET");
        httpService.addParam(type="header", name="Authorization", value="Basic skhdgfkfsdfhskdfh");
        httpService.addParam(type="header",name="Content-Type",value="application/xml");
        httpService.addParam(type="header", name="SOAPAction", value="");
        result = httpService.send().getPrefix();
        writeDump(xmlparse(result.FileContent));
        ws = getSOAPRequest('https://hiddenurl.oraclecloud.com:443/crmService/FoundationPartiesPersonService');
        writedump(ws);
    </cfscript>
    <cfcatch>
        <cfif cfcatch.message contains "Could not perform web service invocation">
            No records found.
            <Cfdump var="#cfcatch#">
        <cfelse>
            Unexpected error in invocation of web service.<cfdump var="#cfcatch#">
        </cfif>
        <cfabort>
    </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```

but i am not getting the results, i seems confused here how am i doing it

error i got while trying @rrk code

`C:\ColdFusion2021\cfusion\stubs\WS_-1374943156_2\src\org\w3\www\_2001\xmlschema\AnySimpleType.java:81: error: cannot find symbol if (local==null){ ^ symbol: variable local location: class AnySimpleType C:\ColdFusion2021\cfusion\stubs\WS_-1374943156_2\src\org\w3\www\_2001\xmlschema\AnySimpleType.java:87: error: cannot find symbol xmlWriter.writeCharacters(org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.ConverterUtil.convertToString(local)); ^ symbol: variable local location: class AnySimpleType C:\ColdFusion2021\cfusion\stubs\WS_-1374943156_2\src\org\w3\www\_2001\xmlschema\AnySimpleType.java:277: error: cannot find symbol org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.ConverterUtil.convertToString(local) ^ symbol: variable local location: class AnySimpleType Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. Note: C:\ColdFusion2021\cfusion\stubs\WS_-1374943156_2\src\com\oracle\xmlns\apps\cdm\foundation\parties\personservice\applicationmodule\PersonServiceStub.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations. Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details. 3 errors`

Comment: While I have used CF to consume SOAP web services in the past, it was before there was a getSOAPRequest() function so I have not used that personally. However, from the docs it looks like you may need to create the webservice object by using the createobject funtion first, then use the getSOAPRequest() on that object.  see the example on https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/getsoaprequest.html

Comment: i am doing that way, using createObject but it is ending in error, here is what i have tried

```<cfscript>
    ws = CreateObject(
        "webservice",
        "https://hiddenurl.oraclecloud.com/foundationParties/PersonService?wsdl"
    );
    writedump(ws); //should show all functions
    abort;
    // req = getSOAPRequest(ws);
    // writedump(req);
</cfscript>``` and that one is also throwing the same error as above,

Comment: if i browser that in rowser, i see the xml tree